# How to finish current page in Windows Universal

Tags: windows, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, uwp

How can I close the current active Page in UWP development?

I want to start a new Page and close the current one, so the user cannot go back to that page. 
Is there any method in UWP similar to Android's method "finish()"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should be able to do this by removing last page from back stack after navigating to a new one. Sample code in *OnNavigatedTo* of a new page:

```cs
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    this.Frame.BackStack.RemoveAt(this.Frame.BackStack.Count - 1);
}
```

This should prevent user from going back to last page. Of course you can modifay the back stack in many ways if you need.