# Can I prevent a page from being included in navigation stack?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, template10

I'm using Template10 to develop a UWP application. It's a series of data entry screens. Each page depends on information entered on the previous page. Not all pages are required based on how they answer the questions on previous screens. If the user navigates back (using the OS back button) and changes data on that screen, it needs to invalidate the data on some or all the screens after it. However, by using the back button there's now a forward stack and if the user navigates forward they're taken to a screen that may have invalid data or not be required to display anymore.

We're using the `NavigationService.Navigate()` method to move forward in the data entry process.

Is there a way to prevent a page from showing up in the navigation stack so the user can't go back to it? This would force them to use the *in app* navigation buttons that we've built to control the users route through the data entry process.

It feels like we're fighting against a design paradigm that we just don't understand. Maybe there's a better way to approach this problem, but we haven't seen it.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: yes you can remove the backstack entries thru ClearHistory

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35090453/2681948) may help as for the backstack, something similar should also be for forward stack.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll look into managing the BackStack within my navigation code.